# cannot find symbol in JLabel extended class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, actionlistener

Is this not valid?

```
public class LayerItem extends JLabel{
    public LayerItem(){
        this.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get an error on line 3 saying: `cannot find symbol: method addActionListener(<anonymous ActionListener>)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `addActionListener` is not available for `JLabel` components.

Comment: WOW, I feel like an idiot now. Thanks I wanted `addMouseListener`